# Setup of Symfony 3.1 cache component with Redis

Tags: php, symfony, redis, symfony-3.1, symfony-cache

I try to setup Symfony 3.1 cache with Redis. I follow this tutorial:

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-cache-component

I've installed predis/predis and SncRedisBundle.

In my config.yml I've put

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: redis://192.168.34.10
    snc_redis:
     clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://192.168.34.10
            logging: %kernel.debug%
        cache:
            type: predis
            alias: cache
            dsn: redis://192.168.34.10
            logging: %kernel.debug%
            options:
                connection_timeout: 10
                read_write_timeout: 30
```

Now when I try to access redis via `snc_redis` it works normally. But when I try to use cache component:

```
public function getLoggedUserAcl($userId)
{
    $cachedResources = $this->cacheAdapter->getItem('acl.rules');
    $cachedResources->expiresAfter(100);

    if ($cachedResources->isHit()) {
        dump('hit');
        $resources = $cachedResources->get();
    } else {
        dump('not-hit');
        $resources = $this->api->getCollection(Resource::class, null, null, [
            'userId' => $userId
        ]);

        $cachedResources->set($resources);
    }

    return $resources;
}
```

CacheAdapter is `@cache.app` service.

It dumps all the time `NOT_HIT`. In logs there is nothing regarding REDIS.

Could you tell me where I've made mistake or give me a hint what may be wrong?

Comment: Missing `$this->cacheAdapter->save($cachedResources);`

Comment: I can't believe it was so trivial. Thank you @malcolm can you post your comment as answer I'll accept it. It works.

Comment: Thanks :) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important thing you missed here is to save result to cache:

```
$cachedResources->set($resources);

$this->cacheAdapter->save($cachedResources);
```